# Wrong between const and string

Tags: string, react-native, constants

## **react native passing const and expect string erorr**

> I'm trying to pass apple key but im getting an error saying that const apikey : google string ... any idea ?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import Purchases,{
    CustomerInfo,
    PurchasesOffering,
} from "react-native-purchases";

const APIKeys = {
    apple: "appl_KDUGooX",
    google: "your_revenuecat_api_key",
};
const typeOfMembership = {
    monthly: "proMonthly",
    yearly: "proYearly",
};

function useRevenueCat(){
  const [currentOffering,setCurrentOffering] = 
  useState<PurchasesOffering | null>(null);
  const [customerInfo,setCustomerInfo] = 
  useState<CustomerInfo | null>(null);

  const isProMember = 
  customerInfo?.activeSubscriptions.includes(typeOfMembership.monthly) || 
  customerInfo?.activeSubscriptions.includes(typeOfMembership.yearly);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);

            if (Platform.OS == "android") {
                await Purchases.configure({ apikey: APIKeys.google });
                } else {
                await Purchases.configure({ apikey: APIKeys.apple });
                }
            const offering = await Purchases.getOfferings();
            const customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();    
            
    }
 },[])
}
export default useRevenueCat;
```

Where can i change it to make it correctly ??

Comment: Argument of type '{ apikey: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PurchasesConfiguration'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'apikey' does not exist in type 'PurchasesConfiguration'. Did you mean to write 'apiKey'?ts(2345).. this is what is the error says ... any help ??

Comment: did you try doing what the error suggests?

Comment: Yes.. could't fix it ...

Comment: in the question text, it still says `({ apikey: APIKeys.google })` and `{ apikey: APIKeys.apple })`.  If you changed those to be `apiKey`, can you change it in your question text as well?